# Cannot properly send data via address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Everyone! 
I am new to MVC framework and recently, I faced with one trouble:

I have a "EditInfo" Controller + basic logic, but I cannot understand one thing -

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(string id)
    {

       // string username = "test_pacient@gmail.com"; <-- THIS ACTUALLY WORKS
        string username = id; // <-- AND THIS NOT + 404-NotFoundError
        // Fetch the userprofile
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

        // Construct the viewmodel
        ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = user.Email,
            PacientInfo = user.PacientInfo
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

So, as you can see I can use initiate "username" field with any value and my logic works as intended, but everytime I try to use send value via address bar - I get a 404 error

There is a View code if it helps to solve my problem :

```
  @foreach (var user in Model.Pacient)
      {    
          <p>
              <strong>@user.Username | @ViewBag.Pacient | @Html.ActionLink("Обновить информацию о пациенте ", "EditPacientInfo", "Doctor",new {id = user.Username}) </strong>
          </p>
      }
```

It would be great if you could add or find some code/stuff that could really help here(Thanks a lot!)

**UDPATE**
I changed my ActionLink method in view (thanks to **T_Roy**) and I finally could send data to address bar, but I got a new problem - if I initiate a "username" field in controller - my logic works, nor if I initiate it via address bar

Do I missing smth important to make my controller`s action use GET parameter?
(Here is GET+POST Methods):

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(string id)
    {

       // string username = "test_pacient@gmail.com"; <-- THIS ACTUALLY WORKS
        string username = id.ToString();<-- AND THIS NOT + 404-NotFoundError
        // Fetch the userprofile
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

        // Construct the viewmodel
        ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = user.Email,
            PacientInfo = user.PacientInfo
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(ApplicationUser pacient)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            // Get the userprofile
            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

            // Update fields
            user.Email = pacient.Email;
            user.PacientInfo = pacient.PacientInfo;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctor"); // or whatever
        }

        return View(pacient);
    }
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on your action do you hit it? Show us the generated URL (F12 in your browser)

Comment: @CodeNotFound, User below has already helped ,but i got stuck with problem in Update paragraph - i would be really greatful if you can help with solution.

Comment: Check with mouse over of the action link it contains url or not.. in browser

Answer (score -1):

That is because your implementation of `@Html.ActionLink` helper method is incorrect.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

There is not an overload that accepts 3 string objects and then 1 object (in your case, is your route values).

You need to use this overload method of the ActionLink helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So in your case:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Обновить информацию о пациенте ", "EditPacientInfo", "Doctor",new {id = user.Username}, null)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks @T_Roy! It really worked , but not i get another type of problem - it gets value to address bar,but my application keeps getting 404 error. I think there is some trouble with controller logic ,but i cannot guess where,because if initiate "username " field - it works ,not if i initiate it with address bar (I`ve updated my question)

Comment: it also have overload for public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
) check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni what are you talking about?  I just looked at the link you provided.. there is no overload that accepts `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues`... The only overload that has those options is `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
 string linkText,
 string actionName,
 string controllerName,
 object routeValues,
 object htmlAttributes`... I assume you're the one who downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

[I should've used a [Route] attribute before GET-method to pass data properly via the address bar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

This is how the code should be written in this case:

```
[Route("Doctor/EditPacientInfo/{name}")]
public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(string name)
{

    // string username = "test_pacient@gmail.com"; <-- THIS ACTUALLY WORKS
    string username = name;
    // Fetch the userprofile
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
    ViewBag.Email = user.Email;
    // Construct the viewmodel
    ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser()
    {          
        PacientInfo = user.PacientInfo
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

- An @ActionLink to combine with [Route] attribute :

  ```
  @Html.ActionLink("A link name  ", "EditPacientInfo",  " Doctor",new {name = user.Username},null)
  ```